# jQuery tools validator affects `event.target behavior`

Tags: internet-explorer-8, validation, jquery-tools

The following code is using jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery tools 1.2.5.
On **radio click**, it evaluates `$(event.target).attr('id')` as 'undefined' in IE 8.  Probably on other versions of IE as well. It works as expected on most other browsers.

When commenting out the instantiation of `$('form').validator()` the code runs as expected even on IE.

Please advise.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jquery tools validator and IE issue on event.target</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js?foo"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').validator();
        $('[type=radio]').click(function(event){
            alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="aee-ee-eight" id="id-0" value="0" checked="checked" tabindex="0">
        <input type="radio" name="aee-ee-eight" id="id-1" value="0" tabindex="1">
        <input type="radio" name="aee-ee-eight" id="id-2" value="0" tabindex="2">
        <input type="submit"><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with `event.target` try using this instead to pick up the target value.

I would change your function to be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').validator();
        $('[type=radio]').click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
```

Comment: well this is true for this example, but my actual code is using proxying .click(myProxy(function(event) and i don't have access to "this"

Comment: the problem is that ie doesn't interpet event.target

Comment: well, isn't jQuery taking care of that? If you comment out the validator() line, the code works as expected, as i mentioned.